# "Vendorize" using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I have been using `setup.py` for packages such as [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), without finding out the details of what `setup.py` does. Things work fine when it's done on the default Python installation on my PC.

Now I want to use gspread in a GAE project. It requires "[vendorizing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring)", something like installing into the `lib` folder inside my application directory. How do I specify that with `setup.py`?

I tried using the [home scheme](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme) and ran:

```
c:\Python27\python setup.py install --home="D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp"
```

but it said:

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python\
c:\Python27\pythonw.exe -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python\ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python\

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp` to your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable. In Windows you can go under `Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables` and then edit the `PYTHONPATH` system variable. The paths are separated by semi-colons so just add it on to the end, `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;"D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp"`.

Comment: I added that to the PYTHONPATH parameter, but it won't install. It installed without errors if I specified instead `D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python`.  Everything that was added seemed to be in ...myapp\lib\python.  However, when I tried importing in my code, it said `ImportError: No module named gspread`.

Comment: Well of course after you install this in a non-standard location, you will need to add a new place for python to check for modules. This is what [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) is for, so just `sys.path.append("D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python")` and then try `import gspread`. Keep in mind this will only be local to that current script.